# converting int to timestamp or any date format sql

Tags: python, sql, amazon-redshift

I am pulling from a db and have a row that has a timestamp and I want it to show up as a date in my python script. 
Here is an example of the data

```
1422471599
1422471599
1422471599
```

Here is what I am trying to do in sql

```
convert(timestamp, cast(time as varchar(12)))
```

I would also be willing to try and convert this in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [datetime.fromtimestamp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp):

```
from datetime import date

s = 1422471599

print(date.fromtimestamp(s)
2015-01-28
```

Comment: any idea how to do that in the query? It would make my script a lot faster

Comment: so you have a dataframe or what exactly? Where are `1422471599 ..` coming from?

Comment: its a df after I pull the data from a database. I use the pandas package to get it in a df

Comment: So you want to convert the column from timestamp to date?

Comment: when I get it from the sql its in decimal format. but I want it in timestamp

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what you actually want, if yo have a dataframe where you have a column with all those timestamps you can easily convert them to  dates.

Comment: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>

Comment: can you add a small sample of your dataframe?

Comment: I unfortunately cannot. What questions do you have?

Comment: So something like `df = pd.to_datetime(df,unit='s')` does not work?

Comment: how can I specify the column in my df?

Comment: the df is called data so data['time']

Comment: Yes, that will do it, `df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"],unit='s')`

Answer (score 0):

```
select timestamp 'epoch' + your_column *  interval '1 second' from your_table;
```

Source: [valkrysa blog post](http://www.valkrysa.com/tech/2015/1/30/amazon-redshift-converting-unix-epoch-time-into-timestamps)